# Parse.com Textview don`t show anything

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, textview, parse-platform

I want to add some non editable text(it`s some description of toys in my app) via parse and I am stuck with the code.

This part (I think) I should change, but don`t know how.

Thanks
I`ve got it already like this
 - (void) retrieveFromParse {

> ```
>     PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
>     [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>         if (!error) {
>             colorsArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
>         }
>         [colorsTable reloadData];
>     }];
>     [self.colorsTable reloadData];
>     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
> }
> ```

This is fully TableViewcontroller.m

> ```
> #import "TableViewController.h"
> #import "CustomCell.h"
>
>
> @interface TableViewController (){
>
>
> }
>
> @end
> @implementation TableViewController
>
>
> @synthesize colorsTable;
>
>
> - (void) retrieveFromParse {
>
>     PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
>     [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
>         if (!error) {
>             colorsArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
>         }
>         [colorsTable reloadData];
>     }];
>     [self.colorsTable reloadData];
>     [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
> }
>
> - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
> {
>     self = [super initWithStyle:style];
>     if (self) {
>         // Custom initialization
>     }
>     return self;
> }
>
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
>
>     UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
>
>     self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
>
>     [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveFromParse)
> ```
>
> forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
>
> ```
> }
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
> {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> #pragma mark - Table view data source
>
> - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
> {
>     // Return the number of sections.
>     return 1;
> }
>
> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {
>     // Return the number of rows in the section.
>     return colorsArray.count;
> }
>
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> {
>     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"colorsCell";
>
>     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
>
>     PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>
>
>
>      [cell.imageview setFile: [tempObject objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]];
>
>
>     [cell.imageview loadInBackground];
>
>
>     cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
>     cell.cellDescript.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];
>
>
>     return cell;
> }
>
>
>
> @end
> ```

DetailViewController.m

> ```
> #import "DetailViewController.h"
> #import "Parse/Parse.h"
>
> @interface DetailViewController ()
>
> @end
>
> @implementation DetailViewController
>
> - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
> {
>     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
>     if (self) {
>         // Custom initialization
>     }
>     return self;
> }
> -(void)parseview
> {
>     NSString *showText = _textdescript.text;
>
>     PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
>     [addValues setObject: showText forKey:@"TextView"];
>
>
> }
>
>
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     [self performSelector:@selector(parseview)];
> }
>
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
> {
>     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> @end
> ```

DetailViewController.h

```
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
> 
> @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
> <UITextViewDelegate>
> 
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textdescript; @end
```

Comment: The best debug step is NSLog(@"%@", showText); right after you set it.  Once you see text in the console, you can worry about parse related issues.  I see at least one, which is the code creates a new parse object (addValues) and then abandons it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property to the second view controller. Set it when preparing the segue or creating the instance with the identifier.

---

This code:

```
- (void)parseview
{
    NSString *showText = _textdescript.text;

    PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
    [addValues setObject: showText forKey:@"TextView"];
}
```

is creating a new empty parse object and setting some text into it. The text is probably nil or `@""` because you have only just loaded the view when this happens (though you may have some default text in the XIB).

Most likely that you should be doing is getting an object back from Parse and interrogating it to get the text, then set that onto the view:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
PFObject *object = [query getFirstObject]; // synchronous request, not ideal, look at getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock

_textdescript.text = [object valueForKey:@"TextView"];
```

Assuming that you have a class `Hracky1` defined in Parse and that it has a string variable named `TextView`.

Comment: Great, it really helped me. But as you said, it is not ideal, because it shows me still the same text view for all my cells. I tried to do with getFirstObjectInBackgroudWithBlock and it doesn`t work. Can you write me please some example with getFirstObjectInBackgroudWithBlock. I am new to programming in XCode. Btw. I edited my post upside with the code, that doesn`t work me again. I tried that. Thanks

Comment: If you have a table view then you don't want the first object, you want all objects. Consider using `PFQueryTableViewController` and supply `parseClassName` and `textKey`.

Comment: I mean ,that I have just tableview with custom cells with disclosure indicators. And then have Segue to View controller, where I put this Textview.It will look the same?

Comment: So if you already have the table view you should be passing the selected object, not creating a new one. You must already have a query somewhere else...

Comment: Ye, I have got it already but I don`t understand to passing the selected object to next view via segue(to the new Viewcontroller). All I need is just to display that Textview. Sorry for my disorientation but I have never done this before. Thank you (I updated the code)